# Solution to a Constrained problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $\alpha, \beta_1, \beta_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha > 1$ and $2>\beta_1 + \beta_2$. Find the solution of the equation (if it exists)

$$2\beta_1(\alpha-1)(2-(\beta_1+\beta_2))\geq \alpha^2$$

I don't think so the solution exists, if it does any help will be appreciated. And yes $\beta_1, \beta_2 >0$

Comment: Are you looking for any/ all values of $\alpha, \beta_i$ that satisfy or is any of them fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no triples of real numbers $(\alpha,\beta_1,\beta_2)$ such that
$$\alpha\gt 1\quad\text{and}\quad 2\gt\beta_1+\beta_2\quad\text{and}\quad \beta_1\gt 0\quad\text{and}\quad \beta_2\gt 0$$
$$2\beta_1(\alpha-1)(2-(\beta_1+\beta_2))\geq \alpha^2\tag1$$
$(1)$ is equivalent to
$$\alpha^2-2\beta_1(2-\beta_1-\beta_2)\alpha+2\beta_1(2-\beta_1-\beta_2)\le 0\tag2$$

Seeing $(2)$ as a quadratic inequality on $\alpha$, we have, using AM-GM inequality,
$$\begin{align}&4\beta_1^2(2-\beta_1-\beta_2)^2-4\cdot 2\beta_1(2-\beta_1-\beta_2)\\\\&=-4\beta_1^2(2-\beta_1-\beta_2)\left(\beta_2-2+\beta_1+\frac{2}{\beta_1}\right)\\\\&\le -4\beta_1^2(2-\beta_1-\beta_2)\left(\beta_2-2+2\sqrt{\beta_1\cdot\frac{2}{\beta_1}}\right)\\\\&=-4\beta_1^2(2-\beta_1-\beta_2)\left(\beta_2-2+2\sqrt{2}\right)\\\\&\lt 0\end{align}$$
we see that $(2)$ has no real solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of showing there are no solutions:

If possible, let $2\beta_1(\alpha-1)(2-\beta_1-\beta_2)\geqslant\alpha^2$.
$\implies 2\beta_1(\alpha-1)(2-\beta_1)>\alpha^2$
By AM-GM, $\beta_1(2-\beta_1)\leqslant1$, so we must have:

$2(\alpha-1)>\alpha^2 \implies -1>(\alpha-1)^2$

which is clearly false.